# voting status not displayed on voting arrows

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

On most stackexchange sites, when you vote up or down, that fills in the up or down arrow, so that it is immediately clear that you have done so (or that you have not voted up or down).

On this site there is no such indication. This is poor design -- please remedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't poor design. That would mean you have to blame [Jin](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/jin), while it actually was a bug I introduced this morning. Fixed now.

Comment: Still not working as of this comment

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Please check if your browser still has the old stylesheet cached; if refreshing it doesn't fix this, please tell me what browser you're using. I've tested Chrome, Firefox, IE7 & IE8, and I see the voting arrows just fine in all of them.

Comment: I had cleared cache and it wasn't working when I commented above an hour ago, but I re-cleared just now and it's working as expected.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Okay, thanks.

Comment: yay, thank you!!!!!